# Error testing ejb 3.1 (netbeans-glassifish-junit4)

Tags: datasource, java-ee-6, jndi, junit4, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to unit testing a EJB with entity crud operations. I already was capable of testing it just running my web application (and all works), but I want to do it with JUnit.

So, my environment is Netbeans 7, Glassfish 3.1 (JavaDB, EclipseLink), JUnit4.

When I create a test class for my EJB, the code template uses the following line of code that throw an exception when I run the code:

```
EJBContainer container = javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

the exception is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/mine__pm
Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jdbc/mine__pm
```

My EJB has an injected `EntityManager` that points to my persistence unit. This persistence unit is referencing a data source that I JNDI named `jdbc/mine` created by Netbeans for my Glassfish. It runs and I can see it on my server. I tried using a `glassfish-resource.xml` to do the same thing too.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: How did you configure your PersistenceUnit's DataSource in persistence.xml?

Comment: <jta-data-source>jdbc/mine</jta-data-source>

Comment: I guess that you'd need to specify your JDBC connection details (using `javax.persistence.jdbc.*` properties in `persistence.xml`) if you want to use the JPA from your Java SE environment.

Comment: why i need to do that if all already works without the junit testing?

Comment: So it does work outside of the container - in Java SE?

Comment: I'm using java ee 6. Running it with the glassfish works. The problem is testing with the embedded container. I suppose i don't need to change anything on the persistence.xml to be able to junit test it.

Comment: Why do you think so? There are certain properties or elements in `persistence.xml` which are intended to be used in Java SE and some which are to be used by Java EE. I.e. you cannot rely on Entity scanning by annotations in Java SE, but you can in EE.

Comment: I will try it later, But still it doesn't make much sense to need a specific project configuration just for test, it is a bad practice. Also, this link show an example of what i'm trying to do http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-junit.html ironically i got the same error following the tutorial or downloading the code that is suppose to work. The error changes depending how i run it, if i run the test from the file (run file) it gives my error above, but if i run the test from the project (project->Test) it says that i have zero ejbs. maybe is my environment.